# clang-format in VSCodium breaking when using some rules

Tags: format, lint, clang-format

I'm trying to define custom format rules, and for some reason `clang-format` reverts to the default rules, despite my file having no discernable mistakes.

More precisely, I'm trying to define use detailed rules for `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations`. This `.clang-format` file works :

```yaml
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
UseTab: "Always"
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
```

And this one, which should give the *exact same result*, breaks and reverts to default format :

```yaml
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
    Enabled: true
UseTab: "Always"
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is the extension broken ? My file seems completely valid to me, but I very well could be wrong. Also please note this is a deliberately reduced example, even when specifying more options, the rule still breaks the entire file.

I'm using VSCodium 1.75.0 on macOS 13.2.1, with the `clangd` extension version 0.1.23 ; as far as I have checked those are the latest versions of everything.

---

Looking at `clangd`'s output in the console, this is what it says about the affected rule :

```
/Users/crysambrosia/Developer/Project/.clang-format:2:2: error: unknown enumerated scalar
        Enabled: true
```

This changes to whatever the first variable is, no matter which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is available in clang-format 15. You seem to use the older clang-format. It's unclear from your question what clang-format do you uses. VSCode, macOS, clangd all their versions are unrelated to clang-format. Compare https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html and https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html in two browser tabs. You will see the difference.

Comment: The clangd extension makes it completely opaque which version of clang-format it uses, so I guess I'll try different format versions until something works. Thank you !